# systemd-resolved stub resolver is dropping connections, and not responding to queries. Why is this?

Tags: debian, systemd, dns, systemd-resolved

I'm having some issues getting DNS Over TLS configured natively using systemd's resolved.

My steps to configure:

1. modify my /etc/systemd/resolved.conf file (this can be seen below)
2. restart resolved via systemctl restart systemd-resolved
3. create a symlink from systemd-resolved's /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolve.conf -> /etc/resolv.conf
4. double check /etc/resolv.conf is right, and is pointing to my local stub resolver 127.0.0.53:53
5. also checked list of listening sockets, and resolved does seem to be listening on udp port 53 on interface 127.0.0.53

I can't seem to understand what is happening here, and why my connection is timing out and the server won't respond to my dns queries. I'm obviously making a huge blunder somewhere, because i believe this should be working. Anyone out there that may understand this better know where to look next?

Here is my /etc/systemd/resolved.conf file:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 2606:4700:4700::1111 2606:4700:4700::1001
# Google:     8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9 2620:fe::fe
DNS=9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=yes
#Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

Here is my /etc/resolv.conf file (which is a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

Comment: i can run a dig command for localhost to server 127.0.0.53#53 and get an answer. dig localhost

Comment: changed DNS= in my /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to DNS=9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net -- but still no dice.

Comment: Try to disable DNSSEC. It's barely working and is not needed for DoT (DNS-over-TLS).